# ruby cucumber tests on multiple browsers

Tags: ruby, testing, cucumber, watir, rubymine

I am using windows 10 32 bit ruby version 233, I am facing these issues with running the tests on a ie 11 browser and the chrome browser for the tests(using page object) that are already running on firefox browser,

> ISSUE with IE: Watir::Exception::NoMatchingWindowFoundException:
>   browser window was closed (eval):1:in `process_watir_call'
>
> ISSUE with Chrome: Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Failed to open TCP connection
>   to 127.0.0.1:9515 (No connection could be made because the target
>   machine actively refused it. - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 9515)

**i have used the following hooks for ie and chrome:**

```
Before do
  case $browser
    when 'mozilla'
      @browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
      @browser.window.maximize
    when 'chrome'
      @browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :profile => "default"
    when 'ie'
      @browser = Watir::Browser.new :ie
      # @browser.window.maximize
      # @browser.visible = true
    else
      @browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
      @browser.window.maximize
  end

  # @browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
  # @browser.window.maximize
  # this file contains test data that needs to be changed if tests are being executed in a different environment
  $test_data = YAML.load_file('features/support/input_data/data/login_information.yml')
  # this file contains base URL that needs to be changed if tests are being executed in a different environment
  FigNewton.load('default.yml')
end
```

I was able to run a small sample test on a separate project from ruby mine with  Watir gem. 
Is there any way to make it work on the existing firefox tests?

Comment: I have tried changing registry settings too nothing seems to work.

Comment: Are you requiring watir or watir-webdriver ?   When you run `gem list watir` what is listed (including version numbers)?  Which lines of your code do the two errors above point to as failing, and can you show us those?

Comment: I tried requiring both watir and watir-webdriver resulted in the same. I am using page-object gem with the watir. gem list watir has given this result:  commonwatir (4.0.0)
watir (6.10.2, 5.0.0 x86-mingw32, 4.0.2 x86-mingw32)
watir-classic (4.3.0, 3.7.0)
watir-webdriver (0.9.9, 0.9.1). The error is pointing to the code which is entering the first field it is expecting.

Comment: Watir::Exception::NoMatchingWindowFoundException: browser window was closed
(eval):1:in `process_watir_call'
./features/support/pages/Messaging/login_page.rb:66:in `enter_username_forward_receiver'
./features/step_definitions/loginpage.rb:21:in `/^I enter my username and click on continue$/'
./features/Messages/loginpage.feature:11:in `When I enter my username and click on continue'

Comment: Chuck van der Linden thank you for responding found the solutions for both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution for IE too its something to do with the internet options security and lower down the security level and uncheck the Enable Protected Mode.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with chrome has been fixed by using the right chromedriver version, but still having problems with the IE using watir.